# GET URL Value to load a pop-up box with content

Tags: jquery

Need help why this code is not working I want that after submitting a form a pop-up box will show after the page loads 
these are my code

**in script.js**

```
$(window).load(function(newSubscriber) {});

function newSubscriber() {
    var URL = $(location).attr('href');
    var GET_ARR = URL.split('/');
    if ($.inArray('?subscriber=yes', GET_ARR)) {

        $("#list-builder").delay(delay).fadeIn("fast", () => {
            $("#popup-box").fadeIn("fast", () => {});
        });
        $("#popup-box-content").html("<p style='text-align: center'>Thank you for subscribing to our mailing list!</p>");
    }
}
```

**action.php**

```
if ($stmt -> execute()) {
    header("Location:index.php?subscriber=yes");
}
```

**html file**

```
<div id="list-builder"></div>
<div id="popup-box">
    <img src="assets/images/close.png" id="popup-close" />
    <div id="popup-box-content">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: instead of this `$(window).load(function(newSubscriber){});` use 
 this one `$(window).load(newSubscriber);` it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These works!

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
 newSubscriber();
});

function newSubscriber(){
var URL = $(location).attr('href');
 var GET_ARR = URL.split('?');

 if(GET_ARR[1] == 'subscriber=yes'){

    $("#popup-box").fadeIn("fast", () => {});
         $("#popup-box-content").html("<p style='text-align: center'>Thank you for subscribing to our mailing list!</p>");

          $("#popup-close").click(() => {
            $("#list-builder, #popup-box").hide();
          });

}

}
```